# How can I concatenate multiple clipboard selections in Quicksilver?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, applescript, concatenation, quicksilver

I've been using Quicksilver's clipboard module for years but I've always wanted to do this: copy several bits of text. Then paste them as a concat'd list.

I found this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907266/copy-concatenation-in-applescript-as-a-command) trying to do something similar with an applescript. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Anything that would allow me to paste multiple items from my clipboard history in one shot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some work has been done on this and merged, you could ask directly whether the changes should solve your problem: http://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/pull/1828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Quicksilver folks [saw this post](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/pull/1828) and coded a solution!

Using the newest release of Quicksilver 1.2.0 (4008) you can

1. select multiple items from your clipboard history (or any other text item)
2. then run the “Type Text” action

It only works for outputting plain text, but it works!

Comment: Unclear how to select multiple items? Mouse and shift+arrows and cmd key don't seem to work

Comment: Ah, it's often referred to as "the comma trick". Select something, hit comma, find something else, hit comma, (repeat until you have all your stuff selected). More info: http://www.43folders.com/2005/06/13/quicksilver-the-comma-trick